# Python QTableView : how to insert items in the columns

Tags: python, pyqt4, multiple-columns, qtableview

I'm a beginner in Python and in Qt so I'm sure the solution to my problem will be really easy for you, but still, it will help me a lot.

I'm using a database where last_name and first_name are stored. I can access to those information but I'm not able to insert them in the QTableView using the QStandarItem.

Here's my code:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT last_name, first_name FROM sakila.actor ORDER BY last_name ASC")
 data = cursor.fetchall()
 model = QStandardItemModel()
 model.setColumnCount(2)
 headerNames = []
 headerNames.append("Last Name")
 headerNames.append("First Name")
 model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerNames)

 for d in data:
     # Create an item with information of the database
     item = QStandardItem(d[0])
     item.setEditable(False)
     model.appendRow(item)
 self.tableViewPatient.setModel(model)
```

so I'm making the Query with :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT last_name, first_name FROM sakila.actor ORDER BY last_name ASC")
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Then I create the table with the headers doing:

```
model = QStandardItemModel()
model.setColumnCount(2)
headerNames = []
headerNames.append("Last Name")
headerNames.append("First Name")
model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerNames)
```

Then for each tuple "Last_name" and "First_name" I put only the Last_Name in the table doing:

```
for d in data:
    # Create an item with information of the database
    item = QStandardItem(d[0])
    item.setEditable(False)
    model.appendRow(item)
self.tableViewPatient.setModel(model)
```

So I get a table which looks like this: 
(sorry, I cannot post an image)

---

### | . | Last Name | First Name |

### | 1 | Dupont    | .......... |

### | 2 | Melkor    | .......... |

### | 3 | Dubois    | .......... |

My problem is thus: **I don't know how to display the first names in the second column for each person.
I know I can get the first_name of each "d" (from data) doing d[1] but I have no idea how to put it in the second column**. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

The [appendRow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#appendRow) method can take either a single `QStandardItem`, or a list of them.

So you want something like:

```
for d in data:
    row = []
    for name in d:
        item = QStandardItem(name)
        item.setEditable(False)
        row.append(item)
    model.appendRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser ekhumo, it works perfectly !